# How is the following code evaluated in C?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

```
#include<stdio.h> 

int main()
{ 
  int const SIZE=5; 
  int expr; 
  double value[SIZE]={2.0,4.0,6.0,8.0,10.0}; 
  expr=1|2|3|4; 

  printf("%f",value[expr]); 
  return 0; 
}
```

How is the above code evaluated? Especially the statement:

```
expr=1|2|3|4;
```

Comment: Do you know what is `|`?

Comment: `value[expr]` --->  undefined behavior

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo What do you means? array out of index is defined behavior in in C99? No..  in OP question `value[expr]` causes out-of-index

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan woops, I thought you where referring to the `double value[SIZE]` part and using `expr` as a general placeholder. Yeah, I guess it would be funny to have such a "feature" in C ;)

Answer (score 8):

It's a [bitwise OR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operations_in_C).

This line:

```
expr=1|2|3|4;
```

is like:

```
expr = b0001 | b0010 | b0011 | b0100;
```

So:

```
0001
0010
0011
0100
----
0111

expr = b0111;

expr = 7;
```

Comment: And when it will come to `printf("%f",value[expr]);`  value[7] will give you random value as it is out of bound for that array!

Answer (score 8):

> Especially the statement: expr=1|2|3|4;

The `|` operator calculates the [*bitwise or*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#OR) of its operands:

```
    1 = 00000001b
    2 = 00000010b
    3 = 00000011b
    4 = 00000100b
    -------------
Result: 00000111b = 7
```

So, you will finally observe [*undefined behaviour*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), since you are accessing an array element which does not exist:

```
expr=1|2|3|4;               // evaluates to 7
printf("%f", value[expr]);  // accesses array element at index 7 which is out of bounds
```

Answer (score 1):

In C (and many other programming languages), | is a bitwise operator OR.

Convert decimal to binary
    1 = 0001 
    2 = 0010
    3 = 0011
    4 = 0100

Hence,
    1|2|3|4 equivalents to
        0001
     OR 0010
     OR 0011
     OR 0100
    =   0111 ( = 7 in decimal)

So expr = 7. 
In this case, accessing value[expr] turns out unexpected result.